# passing a value from one file to another javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a file called functions.js where I have the functiom sum which computes the score that a student takes at a test. I want that sum to be printed into a table in the file admin.php so that the administrator sees all the scores that each student has.

So how can I pass the sum variable to another file? I tried calling the function using the onlick action but that didn't work

Comment: You need a database for that!

Comment: Are you meaning to actually write it to the file on the server, or to pass/store the value somewhere so that the other page can access it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you probably want something like this

```
document.getElementById('saveScoreButton').onclick = {
  var r = new XMLHttpRequest,
    message = document.getElementById('message'),
    score = sum();
  message.innerHTML = 'Saving your score; please wait a second';
  r.open('get', 'savescore.php?score=' + score, true);
  r.send(null);
  r.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (r.readyState == 4 && r.status == 200) {
      message.innerHTML = 'Saved your score';
    }
  }
}
```

This passes the score to a PHP programme `savescore.php` when you click a button with id `saveScoreButton`. The PHP programme then has to retrieve it using `$_GET["score"]`.

Note that this would be easy for the user to trick if they understand javascript and see what is happening. They could just type 'savescore.php?score=100' in the browser's address bar. If you want a secure solution the javascript should only pass the user's answers to the PHP programme, which would then mark the test and sum the results.

It is also possible to use the POST method instead of GET to pass a value:

```
  ...
  r.open('post', 'savescore.php?score=' + score, true);
  r.send('score=' + score);
  ...
```

Then pick it up in the PHP programme using `$_POST["score"]`.

As mentioned in comments, if you want to compare/tabulate scores, then `savescore.php` will  need to store the values in a database or file so that they can be retrieved by `admin.php`.

Comment: The test has multiple choices which can be selected by using a checkbox or a radio button and I compute the sum using document.getElementById('check1').checked. I also tried computing the sum using php using if($_POST['check1']) but I didn't know how to call the function so that it outputs next to the name of the user his score; so I should just compute the sum using php and store it in the database and from there output it on the screen?

Comment: if the aim is just to tell the user his/her score straight away, then you can use `XMLHttpRequest` as above to post the form results, say to a PHP programme called `checktest.php`, which checks the test and `echo`es the score. Javascript can then pick that score up as `r.responseText` in the `r.onreadystatechange` function.

Comment: If you also/instead need (e.g.) to show all scores in a table later on then `checktest` would need to store each score, along with the user's id, in a database or file, so that `admin.php` can access it at another time.

Comment: I want to use the score for 2 things: one to output it in the table from the admin.php file for which I will add a column to the table in the database in which I store all the users and that's easy and the second thing is to output it straight away like you said, only here I have a problem; I wrote a function which computes the sum and it says undefined index 'check1'; I would like when the user clicks the submit button to send him to another page where it outputs the score and where I would also like to show him which were the wrong answers

Comment: Then you might need 3 PHP pages... one for the test itself, one to store the result and show it to the user, and one for the table of all results; and they all need to pass information through the database. Alternatively use javascript to change the test page to show the answers and score after the user has submitted. That could be easier because you wouldn't have to store the users' full answers in the database, only the overall score.

Comment: I will use javascript to pass the user's score to a file from where I will get the score and store it in a database. I have a few questions about your code though: do I have to put it in a functon say getScore() which I will send it at onclick when I push the button for submit? And when I open the page savescores.php and try to get the variable score it says indefined index; can you please help me?

Comment: in the example code I gave, the function runs when a button with id saveScoreButton is clicked, and it also calls a function called `sum` that you mentioned in your original post, that calculates and returns the user's score. As for your PHP error sorry, I have no idea; I suggest making a new question about that with some code, clearly stating what you want it to do and what actually happens.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is ran client-sided, PHP is ran server-sided. Therefor, you have to code something in your javascript which alters the HTML page returned by the PHP script, displaying the result.

Answer (score 1):

Once all of your files are loaded on the client, there isn't a concept of separate js files. The client (browser + javascript) and server (php) are 2 separate entities. When your data is one place the other has no clue it exists. Either research ajax as a method of communicating between the 2 locations or use a form and submit the page to the server.

Good overview of how the server and browser communicate: [How does the communication between a browser and a web server take place?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1764597/how-does-the-communication-between-a-browser-and-a-web-server-take-place)

Basics of Form submission: http://www.htmlgoodies.com/tutorials/forms/article.php/3479121/So-You-Want-A-Form-Huh.htm

Basics of Ajax: http://webdesign.about.com/od/ajax/a/aa101705.htm
Ajax with PHP: http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/simple-ajax-php-and-javascript