# How does a localhost server gets a php page?

Tags: php, localhost, server-side

Im just wondering, when we have a localhost running in our computer for example xampp and we put a index.php in htdocs, how does the server fetches this file when we run the server?

does it use GET?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1764597/how-does-the-communication-between-a-browser-and-a-web-server-take-place

Answer (score 0):

As the file is in the same file system as the web server it uses means of its programming language and the OS to open the file locally. There's no HTTP GET involved.

Answer (score 0):

Your browser uses an HTTP GET, then the web server reads the file on the hard drive and apache mod_php interprets it before returning a response.

Answer (score 0):

A web server running on a local host operates the same as if it were on some other host.

If you are running a web server on your PC whose address is 127.0.0.1:80 and you connect to that URL with a web browser it is the same as if you were connecting to some other host on some other IP address.

I have WAMP that I run on my PC to do work with php and Javascript.  I drop the files into the htdocs folder or subfolders so that they are available however when I access them I use `http://127.0.0.1/xxx.php` to access the php script xxx.php.

I have also written my own web server as an exercise and use the same the same methodology.

If I have MySQL running as well I can pretty much test whatever I want to experiment with on my own PC.

**EDIT**

Here are some additional links to materials.

[w3schools.com HTTP Methods: GET vs. POST](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp)

[w3.org HTTP Header Field Definitions](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html)

[Methods GET and POST in HTML forms - what's the difference](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/methods.html)

Comment: Is it correct to say that my browser uses HTTP GET to get the initial file to load?

Comment: What type of request (GET, POST) will depend on what your browser is doing.  For a standard action of typing a URL into the browser address field such as `http://127.0.0.1/index.php` the browser will use a GET in the HTTP header.  However if you are using a form that you are filling in and then submitting, that would normally be a POST in the HTTP header.  [HTTP Header Field Definitions](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) provides more info about the HTTP header.

Answer (score 0):

In the `/etc/` directory you'll find a config file (mine was `dir.conf`) that defines something like this...

```
<IfModule mod_dir.c> 
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.cgi index.pl index.php index.xhtml index.htm  
</IfModule>
```

That will define where to default page should be and what extensions it should look for (in the order defined)