# How does nodeJS knows which response is for which HTTP request?

Tags: node.js, express, networking

As topic.

**Given** a NodeJS+Express server application serving REST services. From my understanding is that it can handle multiple HTTP requests coming from either; 
1) a same user or 2) various users concurrently.

I also know that for each HTTP requests that came through the application, a corresponding [HTTP.ServerResponse](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_serverresponse) object is created and we typically do stuff like `resp.send(); resp.end()` to reply to the caller.

***Just out of curiosity,*** since the `Http.ServerResponse` object does not seems to contain any properties that can be associated back to the original caller - example IP address. So after Node parses the `ServerResponse` object into data packet, how does Node knows who to reply to?

Comment: HTTP is an _application layer_ protocol. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_protocol_suite#Application_layer) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1764737/4711309).

Comment: @sokin I see so no magic is involved. NodeJS just using the plain old networking stack for handling requests. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: The nice thing about open source projects is that their source code is... well, open. This means that you can hook up with the _http.Server_ class [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/http.js) and from there explore all the way down: First to the [net.Server](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/net.js) class (still in JS realm) and then onto C++ with e.g tcp_wrap.cc [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/src/tcp_wrap.cc) and from there..

Comment: ... to the [V8 engine](https://github.com/v8/v8) itself and [libuv](https://github.com/libuv/libuv) (libuv is written mostly in C). In libuv (among other things) you access the OS's networking API and if you go further down you will meet the NIC's driver all the way until the LAN jack or the WLAN antenna where you enter "reality" and the Physical Layer.

Comment: @sokin Thanks for the detailed stack-by-stack explanation - starting  from the NodeJS layer all the way down to the V8 C library. They are very insightful. Yes, indeed open source is wonderful, especially now we have got places like Stackoverflow filled with people like you - dying to share the knowledge. Would you like to stitch those comments into an answer post? This is so that I can sign it off with a tick and I believe it will also benefit future readers by allowing them to quickly find the answer. Happy to stay this way if you are busy.